# iPhone SDK: Tag friends in Post using Facebook Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I try to post a status with friends tags using FBRequestConnection class method `startForPostStatusUpdate:place:tags:completionHandler:`

As

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:Message
                                            place:nil
                                             tags:[NSArray arrayWithArray:users] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                 [self showAlert:@"" result:result error:error];
                                             }];
```

Where users array contains user id's.

the error message i received "Cannot Specify user tags without place tag".

Please tell me solutions how can i add place parameters in this method.

Comment: I need the exactly the same. Any luck figuring it out.

Comment: Hi @Siddiq have you solved your problem ? I am also want to tag some friends with my post in iOS app Plzzzzz Help?

Answer (score 3):

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"test message with place and tags" place:@"155021662189" tags:@[@"yourFriendID"] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"startForPostStatusUpdate: %@, error: %@", result, error);
}];
```

Use 155021662189 as null value for place